# Ubuntu 13.04 update and install issue

Tags: apt, 13.04, updates, update-manager, gnupg

I've checked several forums and sites for trying to fix this issue. This issue has been happening for the last three days. I'm a bit of a newbie to Linux but I think I've managed to narrow down where the issue is.

I've recently been getting an error like this `E: GPG error: http://arcgive.canonical.com raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2`

every time with "*sudo apt-get update*". Also been getting a red warning triangle warning me update information is outdated and may be caused by network issues or outdated repository. After some intense google searching a few people have had a similar issue but it seemed to be with 13.03.

From what I gather, I am missing GPG keys that is causing the issue (tried resetting them to default in the settings but no luck). There was a link to what appeared to be the PGP key for raring Release but I can't make heads or tails of what to do with it: http://archive.canonical.com/dists/raring/Release.gpg

I am really hoping someone here may know what to do.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please add your answer and then you will be able to accept the answer to close the thread.  Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused due to a misspelled link as you can see in `E: GPG error: http://arcgive.canonical.com raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2` it says "arcgive" it needs to be "archive" to change this, type `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and fix the typo where you see it (in this case: `deb-src http://arcgive.canonical.com/ raring partner` needed to be edited to: `deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ raring partner`) hit save now the issue should be fixed and then type `sudo apt-get update` to check and it should now find any missing updates. This also fixed the issue of not being able to download from the Ubuntu Software Centre or install via apt